# JSONArray.add(new Long(value)) and (Long) JSONArray.get(index) fails

Tags: java, android, json

On the server side I build my JSON as follows:

```
JSONArray mArray = new JSONArray();
mArray.add(new Long(m.matchId)); // matchId is a long value
```

On the client (Android app) I would like to parse the incoming JSON as follows:

```
JSONArray matchesArray = (JSONArray) ms.get(i); 
match.matchId = (Long) matchesArray.get(0);
```

However, then I get an error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

How do I to do this in order to make sure I'm getting the correct long value?

Comment: do `((Number) (matchesArray.get(0))).longValue()` doesn't work?

Comment: Alexandro, that was it. Thank you. Write an answer which I will then checkmark as solved

Comment: if you want a long, call `getLong`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
((Number) (matchesArray.get(0))).longValue();
```

In order to get the `long` value of your number independently of its numeric type.

**EDIT**

As **@njzk2** and **@mvd** point out, and a fast reading about [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getLong(int)), you can just simply use:

```
matchesArray.getLong(0);
```

Comment: overly complicated for no reason.

Comment: if the returned object is not a number, this throws a ClassCastException. Using the built-in coercion methods (e.g. getLong), you leave that part to the JSON parser, which will throw a JSONException if the content is not a long, indicating with more clarity that the json is not what you expect.

Comment: As @njzk2 said, the API provides `get<Type>` methods, which should be used instead of home-baked approaches!

Comment: @njzk2 didn't know about JSONArray, as you say, `getLong()` is a better answer...